# Calculate CRC-6 GSM using lookup table

Tags: delphi, pascal, lazarus, crc

I am trying to calculate CRC-6 GSM but the result is wrong ($16).
For '123456789' it should return $13 according to
https://reveng.sourceforge.io/crc-catalogue/all.htm#crc.cat.crc-6-gsm

```
var Table: array[0..255] of Byte = (
$3F, $10, $0E, $21, $32, $1D, $03, $2C, 
$25, $0A, $14, $3B, $28, $07, $19, $36, 
$0B, $24, $3A, $15, $06, $29, $37, $18, 
$11, $3E, $20, $0F, $1C, $33, $2D, $02, 
$38, $17, $09, $26, $35, $1A, $04, $2B, 
$22, $0D, $13, $3C, $2F, $00, $1E, $31, 
$0C, $23, $3D, $12, $01, $2E, $30, $1F, 
$16, $39, $27, $08, $1B, $34, $2A, $05, 
$31, $1E, $00, $2F, $3C, $13, $0D, $22, 
$2B, $04, $1A, $35, $26, $09, $17, $38, 
$05, $2A, $34, $1B, $08, $27, $39, $16, 
$1F, $30, $2E, $01, $12, $3D, $23, $0C, 
$36, $19, $07, $28, $3B, $14, $0A, $25, 
$2C, $03, $1D, $32, $21, $0E, $10, $3F, 
$02, $2D, $33, $1C, $0F, $20, $3E, $11, 
$18, $37, $29, $06, $15, $3A, $24, $0B, 
$23, $0C, $12, $3D, $2E, $01, $1F, $30, 
$39, $16, $08, $27, $34, $1B, $05, $2A, 
$17, $38, $26, $09, $1A, $35, $2B, $04, 
$0D, $22, $3C, $13, $00, $2F, $31, $1E, 
$24, $0B, $15, $3A, $29, $06, $18, $37, 
$3E, $11, $0F, $20, $33, $1C, $02, $2D, 
$10, $3F, $21, $0E, $1D, $32, $2C, $03, 
$0A, $25, $3B, $14, $07, $28, $36, $19, 
$2D, $02, $1C, $33, $20, $0F, $11, $3E, 
$37, $18, $06, $29, $3A, $15, $0B, $24, 
$19, $36, $28, $07, $14, $3B, $25, $0A, 
$03, $2C, $32, $1D, $0E, $21, $3F, $10, 
$2A, $05, $1B, $34, $27, $08, $16, $39, 
$30, $1F, $01, $2E, $3D, $12, $0C, $23, 
$1E, $31, $2F, $00, $13, $3C, $22, $0D, 
$04, $2B, $35, $1A, $09, $26, $38, $17
);

function GSM_Update(Msg: PByte; Length: Integer): Byte;
var i: Integer;
    H: Byte;
begin
  H :=  $00;

  for i:=0 to Length-1 do begin

    H := Table[H xor Msg^];  //I believe this line might be wrong but don't know how to change it
    Inc(Msg);
  end;

  Result := H xor $3F;
end;
```

Invoking is quite simple:

```
var Msg: AnsiString;
...
GSM_Update(@Msg[1], Length(Msg));
```

or

```
var Msg: array of AnsiChar;
Len: Integer;
...
SetLength(Msg, Len); 
GSM_Update(@Msg[0], Len);
```

Comment: Where did you copy/translate this from? Link to sources. How are you actually calling your function? Everybody of us has to guess his own way how you could have called it, trying to reconstruct your result.

Comment: There is no link because I generated the array myself and wrote the code based on parameters from the catalog of CRC functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not certain about the Pascal operators and syntax, but for the table in your code, that line needs to be:

```
    H := (not Table[(H shl 2) xor Msg^]) and $3F;
```

This could be simplified and sped up by using a more appropriate table. I would replace each byte in the table by its one's complement shifted left by two bits. I.e. `$00, $bc, $c4, $78,` ... Then that line would be what you currently have:

```
    H := Table[H xor Msg^];
```

and the last line would need to be changed to:

```
  Result := (H shr 2) xor $3F;
```

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly, of course! So... when is Adler-64 coming out? :)